# How extend actionbar background to statusbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-statusbar

[image: Screenshot] How can I extend the AppBar background to statusbar? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

call this in your `onCreate();`

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
        .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

sets your view layout as full screen and makes status bar colo transparent, works for Api21 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I originally posted a solution based on a external link, that is not working now. This was the code:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

And set `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Before API30, it was possible to achieve the effect using:

1. Theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`
2. Setting window flags:

```
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
        )
```

3. Using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for top layout

I do not know solution for API30+